# Best C# data structure for random order population?

Tags: c#, data-structures, collections

In C# I have a use case where I have a mapping from `int`s to collections.

- the `int`s are a dense (but not packed) set from 1 to n where n is not known.
- The cells will be loaded in random order.
- the marginal cost of each cell should be ideal (as good as a `List<T>` or `T[]`)
- I'd like to have the cells default filled on demand

What is the best structure for this?

A `List<T>` would work well (better in space than a `Dictionary<>`) and by deriving from it I can get much of what I want, but is there something better? As in the best code is code you don't write.

Comment: This question is related to that one:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/481603/set-extend-listt-length-in-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `Dictionary<int, Cell>` sounds like a good match to me. Or you could use a `List<Cell>` quite easily, and just make sure that you expand it where necessary:

```
public static void EnsureCount<T>(List<T> list, int count)
{
    if (list.Count > count)
    {
        return;
    }
    if (list.Capacity < count)
    {
        // Always at least double the capacity, to reduce
        // the number of expansions required
        list.Capacity = Math.Max(list.Capacity*2, count);
    }
    list.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(default(T), list.Capacity-list.Count));
}
```

Comment: I'd like to leverage the dense nature of the keys

Comment: Edited answer while you were commenting :)

Comment: Yup. Your thinking along the same way I am, Has anyone published code for stuffing that into the indexing function?

Comment: Well, you can use extension methods to make it easier to call (just add "this" before the arg in C# 3.0)

Comment: I would suggest doing `list.Capacity = Math.max(count, list.Capacity * 2)`, as this would decrease repeated allocations for repetitive calls for this method.

Comment: @Hosam: yes, that would make sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be a real stickler, one option is to write a facade class which provides a strategy around a number of different mappers.  Make it so that it uses a statically defined array when N is < some value and when the load (packedness) is over some threshold.  Have it swap to a Tree or a Dictionary representation when certain thresholds are passed.

You did not state how you planned on actually interacting with this data structure once it had been built, so depending on what your access / usage patterns are, a mixed strategy might provide a better runtime behavior than sticking with a single data representation.  Think of it in a similar fashion to how quicksort algorithm implementations will sometimes switch to a simpler sort algorithm when the collection to be sorted has less than N data elements.

Cheers!