# Set/extend List<T> length in c#

Tags: c#, list

Given a `List<T>` in c# is there a way to extend it (within its capacity) and set the new elements to `null`? I'd like something that works like a `memset`. I'm not looking for sugar here, I want fast code. I known that in C the operation could be done in something like 1-3 asm ops per entry.

The best solution I've found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481334/best-c-data-structure-for-random-order-population#481350):

```
list.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(null, count-list.Count));
```

however that is c# 3.0 (<3.0 is preferred) and might be generating and evaluating an enumerator.

My current code uses:

```
while(list.Count < lim) list.Add(null);
```

so that's the starting point for time cost.

The [motivation for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481334/best-c-data-structure-for-random-order-population) is that I need to set the n'th element even if it is after the old Count.

Comment: If this is going to happen a lot, I suggest using a Dictionary<int,T> instead of a List<T>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The simplest way is probably by creating a temporary array:

```
list.AddRange(new T[size - count]);
```

Where `size` is the required new size, and `count` is the count of items in the list. <del>However, for relatively large values of `size - count`, this can have bad performance, since it can cause the list to reallocate multiple times.</del>(`*`) It also has the disadvantage of allocating an additional temporary array, which, depending on your requirements, may not be acceptable. You could mitigate both issues at the expense of more explicit code, by using the following methods:

```
public static class CollectionsUtil
{
    public static List<T> EnsureSize<T>(this List<T> list, int size)
    {
        return EnsureSize(list, size, default(T));
    }

    public static List<T> EnsureSize<T>(this List<T> list, int size, T value)
    {
        if (list == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("list");
        if (size < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("size");

        int count = list.Count;
        if (count < size)
        {
            int capacity = list.Capacity;
            if (capacity < size)
                list.Capacity = Math.Max(size, capacity * 2);

            while (count < size)
            {
                list.Add(value);
                ++count;
            }
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

The only C# 3.0 here is the use of the "`this`" modifier to make them extension methods. Remove the modifier and it will work in C# 2.0.

Unfortunately, I never compared the performance of the two versions, so I don't know which one is better.

Oh, and did you know you could resize an array by calling [`Array.Resize<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051.aspx)? I didn't know that. :)

**Update:**
(`*`) Using `list.AddRange(array)` will *not* cause an enumerator to be used. Looking further through Reflector showed that the array will be casted to `ICollection<T>`, and the `Count` property will be used so that allocation is done only once.

Comment: the "list.AddRange(new T[size - count]);" in the comment looks good. I wonder if the optimizer can avoid the enumerator.

Comment: @BCS, I was wrong, the implementation of `List<T>.AddRange` actually optimizes for this case. I have updated my post.

Answer (score 3):

```
static IEnumerable<T> GetValues<T>(T value, int count) {
   for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
      yield return value;
}

list.AddRange(GetValues<object>(null, number_of_nulls_to_add));
```

This will work with 2.0+

Comment: This has the benefit that it fills the list with the required values. But if nulls or zeros are sufficient, simply `list.AddRange(new T[count - list.Count]` would be enough. (And I guess it would perform better at least for small array sizes.)

Answer (score 0):

Since .NET 8 you can use [`CollectionsMarshal.SetCount<T>(List<T>, Int32)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.collectionsmarshal.setcount?view=net-8.0):

> Sets the count of the `List<T>` to the specified value.
> When increasing the count, uninitialized data is being exposed.

```
var ints = new List<int>();
CollectionsMarshal.SetCount(ints, 20);
Console.WriteLine(ints.Count); // Prints "20"
```

Which should be more performant due to reduced allocations.

Answer (score -3):

Why do you want to do that ?
The main advantage of a List is that it can grow as needed, so why do you want to add a number of null or default elements to it ?

Isn't it better that you use an array in this case ?

Comment: IIRC array can't grow (you can make a bigger copy but not grow it)

Comment: List<T> isn't an array.  It can grow.

Comment: I had a similar situation once. I wanted to have direct access to some elements using IDs, but I didn't know how many elements there were in advance. The IDs were not sequential, so I needed the same method the OP is asking for. I have posted my version in an answer.

Comment: Actually arrays *can* grow! I didn't know that, but I just noticed the `Array.Resize()` method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051.aspx

Comment: @Hosam, in that case a Dictionary is usually better

Comment: @configurator: Well, not that much. in my case IDs were usually multiples of 2 (e.g. 2, 4, 6, ...), although not necessarily. And speed was important, thus I chose the List. The number of items is less than 1000, so no big deal. Now I intend to change it to an array after knowing it can be resized.

Comment: Array.Resize() does not change the size of an array.  It creates a new array and copies elements.

Comment: @Lou Franco, you're right. I had thought it could be like `realloc`, but it's not. :(

Comment: "Array.Resize() does not change the size of an array. It creates a new array and copies elements." -- the same is true of a `List` when growing beyond its `Capacity` ... a `List` is just a wrapper around an `Array` and it uses `Array.Resize()` as needed. "I had thought it could be like realloc, but it's not." -- in fact it is; the Array.Resize() implementation uses `realloc` (or a per-OS equivalent) -- which also allocates a new chunk of memory and copies when necessary. You folks are confusing the abstraction with the implementation.