# How to get a copy of an generic type?

Tags: c#, list

In [Hosam Aly's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/481658/1671066) to the question "Set/extend List length in C#" this code is proposed:

```
public static List<T> EnsureSize<T>(this List<T> list, int size, T value)
{
    if (list == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("list");
    if (size < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("size");

    int count = list.Count;
    if (count < size)
    {
        int capacity = list.Capacity;
        if (capacity < size)
            list.Capacity = Math.Max(size, capacity * 2);

        while (count < size)
        {
            list.Add(value);
            ++count;
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

where the value is added to the list by reference. **How can on ensure the size of a list by using *copies* instead?**

(I tried to use `Clone()` and `ICloneable` without success, since some types, e.g. `List<T>` return a shallow copy and I want a deep copy.)

Comment: Please show *how* you tried to use `Clone()`. If a type doesn't support deep-copying, what would you expect it to do? What would you expect this to do if you call it with a `FileStream`, for example?

Comment: _"How can on ensure the size of a list by using copies instead?_ The bold part seems to be important but i don't understand it. **Edit** Apparently you want to create new references. There's no way to do that on any type of object. You need to restrict `T` to types which implement an interface `ICopyable` (todo).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you don't know anything about T, whether it's clonable or serializable or a million other ways to copy it, you will have to rely on the caller to provide such means. You want an arbitrary number of new T's, the the simplest version would be to ask for a generator in your method signature:

```
public static List<T> EnsureSize<T>(this List<T> list, int size, Func<T> generator)
{
    if (list == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("list");
    if (size < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("size");

    int count = list.Count;
    if (count < size)
    {
        int capacity = list.Capacity;
        if (capacity < size)
            list.Capacity = Math.Max(size, capacity * 2);

        while (count < size)
        {
            list.Add(generator());
            ++count;
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

Calling it would look like this:

```
myList.EnsureSize(42, () => new Item());
```

or this:

```
myList.EnsureSize(42, () => existingItem.Clone());
```

or maybe this:

```
myList.EnsureSize(42, () => StaticItemFactory.CreateNew());
```

or any other way to construct a new T.